# How to view error logs generated by mariadb on CentOS 7

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am new to mariadb. Today, I was attempting to import a mysql database to mariadb and during the process the import stops when a warning is encountered as shown below.

[image]

Now, I said to myself that I should check a log file so I can see the error but I can't seem to fine any log file. I ran the query below with help from [Get the error log of Mariadb](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/get-the-error-log-of-mariadb/):

[image]

As you can see there is no path to an error log file.

Next I checked `/var/lib/mysql` and below is the dir content:

```
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql    16384 Jun  5 16:03 aria_log.00000001
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql       52 Jun  5 16:03 aria_log_control
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql 79691776 Jun  8 08:02 ibdata1
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql 50331648 Jun  8 08:02 ib_logfile0
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql 50331648 Jun  5 16:03 ib_logfile1
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql        6 Jun  5 16:12 IMSPRO.pid
drwx------. 2 mysql mysql     4096 Jun  8 08:02 ecommence
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql        0 Jun  5 16:12 multi-master.info
drwx--x--x. 2 mysql mysql     4096 Jun  5 16:03 mysql
srwxrwxrwx. 1 mysql mysql        0 Jun  5 16:12 mysql.sock
drwx------. 2 mysql mysql       20 Jun  5 16:03 performance_schema
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql    24576 Jun  5 16:12 tc.log
```

No file in the above dir logs error.

Below is the content of my `/etc/my.cnf`

```
#
# This group is read both both by the client and the server
# use it for options that affect everything
#
[client-server]

#
# include all files from the config directory
#
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d
```

Below is the content of `/etc/my.cnf.d`

```
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root  117 Jun  5 16:02 .
drwxr-xr-x. 91 root root 8192 Jun  7 01:14 ..
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  295 May 29 16:48 client.cnf
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  763 May 29 16:48 enable_encryption.preset
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  232 May 29 16:48 mysql-clients.cnf
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 1080 May 29 16:48 server.cnf
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  285 May 29 16:48 tokudb.cnf
```

What can I do to get error log?

Comment: You set the log_error variable to a filename, and voila, the file gets created and written to (after a server restart most probably, too lazy to google).

Comment: Hi @fancyPants, where do I place thsi file?

Comment: For mysql the default location is `/var/log/mysql/`. You can place it whereever you want. But usually it's placed on a separate partition, so that the server continues to run even when the log takes up all the space.

Comment: Hi @fantyPants, I have set the log in `server.cnf` like `log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log` and have restarted my server and try the import again and when it stops at the warning, I don't see this log file created.

Comment: `show variables like 'log-error'` now display `/var/log/mysqld.log`

Comment: Might be that you have to create it yourself. Just `touch /var/log/mysqld.log` and make sure, that the mysql user has access rights to it.

Comment: Hi @fancyPants. I have created the file manually and info is written to it but none related to my import. what can I do?

Comment: Warnings are not errors. Have a look at the the log_warnings variable. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_log-warnings

Answer (score 0):

The way to see the warnings is to type this *immediately* after receiving that "Warnings: 1":

```
 SHOW WARNINGS;
```

(As soon as the next *other* command is run, the warnings are cleared.)

Answer (score 0):

In mariadb version 10.3.29,

> #show variables like 'log-error';

is showing "Empty set" output
[image]

[image]

Instead, the following command is working

> show global variables like 'log_error';

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I edited `/etc/my.cnf` and added the line `log_error` after `[mysqld]`:

```
[mysqld]
...
log_error
```

After that, the query `show variables like 'log_error';` displays the following (before the change, the Value column was empty):

```
+---------------+--------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                    |
+---------------+--------------------------+
| log_error     | /var/lib/mysql/host.err  |
+---------------+--------------------------+
```

Now the error log is being written to the above file.

The exact name of the file will vary from server to server and will take the name of the current host, so expect it to be different in your particular case.